# Count how many and which index of a array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects:

```
 result = [
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386df9d, video_id: '1' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386df9e, video_id: '1' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386df9f, video_id: '1' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386dfa0, video_id: '2' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386dfa1, video_id: '2' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386dfa2, video_id: '1' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386dfa3, video_id: '2' },
 { _id: 53d0dfe3c42047c81386dfa4, video_id: '1' } 
 ]
```

I need to create another array, which takes video_id as the index, and contains how many times this video_id appears in the first array:

```
list = [
{'1' : 5},
{'2' : 4}
]
```

Currently, I use this code:

```
while (i < result.length)
{
    if(list[result[i].video_id] === undefined) {
        list[result[i].video_id] = 0;
    }
    list[result[i].video_id] = list[result[i].video_id] + 1;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there is any faster and cleaner way to do so? (the real result array has over 10k elements, and I doubt >10k conditional statements are optimal...).

I am using node.js, result is from a mongoose (mongoDB) query, and I didn't see any way to get this done by mongoose itself:

```
var now = new Date();
//M_logs is a mongoose model
query = M_logs.where('time').gt(new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTime() / 1000).lt(now.getTime() / 1000).select('video_id');
```

(PS: I wonder if this isn't more a Code Review question, please tell me if I am off-topic so I can migrate the question).

EDIT:

To answer to Juan Carlos Farah:

```
S_logs =  new mongoose.Schema({

    user_ip : String,
    user_id : String,
    user_agent : String,
    canal_id :  String,
    theme_id :  String,
    video_id :  String,
    osef : String,
    time : Number,
    action: String,
    is_newuser : String,
    operator : String,
    template : String,
    catalogue : String,
    referer : String,
    from : String,
    osef1 : String

});

M_logs = mongoose.model('logs', S_logs);
```

Comment: What do the documents in M_logs look like?

Comment: Awesome. Just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the aggregation framework. The idea is to do something as follows:

1. Match the documents you are looking for. Based on your current query, I understand it would be documents where `time` is between `new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTime() / 1000` and `now.getTime() / 1000`.
2. Group the matched documents by `video_id` and keep track of their count.
3. Optionally sort by `_id`, which would be equivalent to the original `video_id`.

The following is in `mongo` shell syntax:

```
var now = new Date();

db.M_logs.aggregate([
    {
        "$match" : {
            "time" : { 
                "$gt" : new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTime() / 1000,
                "$lt" : now.getTime() / 1000
            }
        }    
    },
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$video_id",
            "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 }
    }
]);
```

If this works for you, you can easily implement it in Mongoose or Node.js driver syntax. Note that the aggregation framework returns a cursor, which you can iterate through to populate your array.

EDIT:

Using the Node.js driver, you can access the results from the aggregation query in the callback function. Something as follows:

```
...
, function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    db.close();                          
}
```

Note that the Mongoose syntax for aggregation queries is slightly different.

Example:

```
Model.aggregate([ <QUERY> ]).exec( <CALLBACK> );
```

For more information, consult the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate).

Comment: Could you just add how to use the cursor? It s exactly what I need so far : ) (also thanks for the syntax edit on my question)

Comment: @DrakaSAN. Not a problem. Yes I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) to count number of documents. It will be significantly faster than iterating all your documents and counting them.

Using mongoose you can do it like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var startTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTime() / 1000):
var endTime = now.getTime() / 1000;

M_logs.aggregate([
    // filter the documents you're looking for
    {"$match" : { "time" : {"$gt": startTime, "$lt": endTime}}},
    // group by to get the count for each video_id
    {"$group" : {"_id" : "$video_id", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},
    // make the output more explanatory; this part is optional
    {"$project" : { "video_id" : "$_id", "count" : "$count", _id : 0}}
]).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) console.err(err);
    console.log(docs);
});
```

The output of the `docs` will be:

```
[ { count: 4, video_id: '2' }, { count: 5, video_id: '1' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var list = {};
result.forEach(function (el) {
    list[el.video_id] = (list[el.video_id] || 0) + 1;
});
```

the resuling list will look something like this:

```
var list = {
    '1': 5,
    '2': 4
};
```

Comment: Does work, I ll just wait a little to see if other solutions appear : )